# How do I call for a max in an array(pascal)

Tags: max, pascal

I tried:

```
Writeln(max(vaMonth[j,k]));
```

But it wont just give the maximum value. Instead I get: `Illegal Qualifier`. 
All I want is that it writes the max value in within my array...

Comment: See [System.Math.MaxValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.MaxValue).

Comment: You need to provide more information - what environment are you working in, what compiler are you using, how is the array vaMonth declared, and so on. You should post code that represents the minimum needed for someone else to be able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The array needs to be float or integer.

Maybe the following links may help you:
http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/maxvalue.html
http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/maxintvalue.html